# Date data entry, find match and Copy Paste transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to establish a database that I can feed with a data table.
The following table is in one tab and will only contain weekly data.

[image: https://imgur.com/ca5GSu6]

I am looking for code that does an Offset and match by Arrival date in another tab and inputs the data into a Full Year table that is transposed.

I tried several codes that were a solution for  a partial problem, but did not succeed.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Don't quite understand your requirement. What your picture shows is easily achievable with a Copy/Paste-Special>Transpose function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Copy/Paste Transpose would do what your picture shows:
https://youtu.be/mKM5uZxuelk